# The Amazing Spider Man 2 iOS game prologue cutscenes explained

Tags: marvel, video-games, spider-man

I need explanation on the [cutscenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4CkyAEO168), specifically;

- Why there is cellphone device with a hologram inside the flying robot?
- Where did the green thing comes from when he is on the top the truck and what is it?

[image: Spider-Man looking at a cellphone with a hologram coming out of it inside the robot]

[image: Spider-Man on top of a truck with a can flying in the foreground]

Comment: Have you played the game all the way through?

Comment: No.But that thing he grabs it comes from no where..

Comment: the green thing seems to be a trash bin in the street. I don't know the game, but the circled element (that looks yellow to me) is the radioactive product (it has the "radioactive element" symbol on top of it) that Spider-man tries to retrieve from thieves at the beginning of the movie.

Comment: On the movie spider enters inside the truck from the hole on the top of the truck the thieves made,and then he ciollect those radioactive product.On the game this product apear from no whrere as if something happenned and not showed.

Answer (score 2):

In the cut scene, the canister (containing the "radioactive element" mentioned in the previous scene) comes from the side of the truck. It seems logical that the driver had it in the cab with him and tossed it out of the window.

[image: Gif showing the can fly out of the truck's window and Spider-Man leaping off to catch it]

The 'cellphone looking device' appears to be some sort of in-built GPS system for the drones. Presumably used by the drone controller as a programming interface.

Comment: Nice hat-tip to The Simpsons opening sequence there.